# Django dynamic url from calendar

Tags: django, django-templates

The desired url should be '.../journal/year/month'

Index.html

```
<a class="nav-link active " href="{% url 'journal' {{year}} {{month}} %}">Journal</a>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns =[
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('journal/<int:year>/<str:month>/', views.journal, name='journal'),
]
```

Views.py

```
def home(request):
    year = datetime.datetime.now().year
    month = datetime.datetime.now().month
    return render(request, 'base/index.html',{
        'year': year,
        'month': month,
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use variables in a template tag without additional curly brackets, so:

```
<a class="nav-link active " href="{% url 'journal' year month %}">Journal</a>
```

Comment: wow. I feel stupid now. I saw this in the documentation and I thought i had to use them inside double brackets. thanks